# In this code, copied from ch 15 of eloquent javascript, what does the keyup event listener do?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

In the following code, copied from [ch 15 of Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/15_game.html), how does `pressed[codes[event.keyCode]]` end up as a boolean value? I just can't figure out why you need the `'keyup'` event listener.

The idea is to make sure that `'keydown'` gets registered only once when it is being held down.  I thought maybe the keyup event gets fired when you are holding the key down, as this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) reference on the `keydown` event suggests, but that resource says that functionality is discontinued.

```
var arrowCodes = {37: "left", 38: "up", 39: "right"};

function trackKeys(codes) {
  var pressed = Object.create(null);
  function handler(event) {
    if (codes.hasOwnProperty(event.keyCode)) {
      var down = event.type == "keydown";
      pressed[codes[event.keyCode]] = down;
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  addEventListener("keydown", handler);
  addEventListener("keyup", handler);
  return pressed;
}
```

Here is the text explaining this block of code.  I don't get it at all--where do `true` and `false` come from?

> Note how the same handler function is used for both event types. It
> looks at the event object’s type property to determine whether the key state should be updated to true ("keydown") or false ("keyup").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var down = event.type == "keydown";
```

is exactly the same as

```
var down;
if ( event.type == "keydown" ) { down = true; }
else                           { down = false; }
```

If your question is about something else, then please indicate so.

Comment: do new instances of all of those objects get created everytime I run that function?

Comment: Your code creates a [`closure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). Object `pressed` is created when `trackKeys()` (outer function) is called and is available to `handler()` (inner function). Also see [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

Answer (score 1):

The truth values come from the line of code below:

```
var down = event.type == "keydown";
```

It sets `down` to be true if `event.type` is equal to `"keydown"`, false otherwise, and can be read as:

```
var down = (event.type == "keydown");
```

or (far more verbose):

```
var down;
if (event.type == "keydown") {
    down = true;
} else {
    down = false;
}
```

The second line of the then goes on to store that truth value into the `pressed` array:

```
pressed[codes[event.keyCode]] = down;
```

Answer (score 0):

The bool  value comes from
var down = event.type   == "keydown";

precedence of RHS is always more, so first right expression event.type == "keydown" is evaluated and operator in this is "equal to" so the output of this will be based upon result of comparision expression which will be boolean value only.